# Extending RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration breaks Jackson LocalDateTime Serialisation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, java-8, jackson

I'm attempting to extend `RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration` to override the `uriToEntityConverter` for a custom one, however doing that then causes Jackson to fail to be able to serialise/deserialise `LocalDateTime` from `String`. The code below shows my subclass.

I've also tried adding `jackson-datatype-jsr310` into the `pom` to see if I can force support, but without my subclass it works anyway so that was mostly a dead-end.

```
@Configuration
@Import(RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class)
public class RepositoryRestMvcConfigurer extends RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration {

  @Override
  @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.data.rest")
  public RepositoryRestConfiguration config() {
    return super.config();
  }


  @Override
  protected UriToEntityConverter uriToEntityConverter(ConversionService conversionService) {
    return new OverriddenUriToEntityConverter(persistentEntities(), repositoryInvokerFactory(conversionService), repositories());
  }
}
```

EDIT:
I've solved the problem by annotating my `LocalDateTime` properties to specify what serialiser and deserialiser to use, but that feels more like a voodoo ritual than a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I ended up self-solving this. To actually extended that you also need:

- A class that extends `RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter`
- A class that returns that previous class and also implements the annotations for `AutoConfigureAfter`

I based mine on the `RepositoryRestMvcAutoConfiguration` class actually within *Spring* but changed it from being `@ConditionalOnMissingBean(RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class)` to `@ConditionalOnBean(ExtendedRepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class)`. That allowed it to properly configure the `RestRepository` with my overridden functions.

Comment: can you post your code? I am confused how you resolved it.

Comment: I'll have to do it tomorrow when I've got my laptop, but I'll put a sample project on Github.

Comment: Here's a sample project for you, I've not fully tested it but it shows how to extend and which bits you need to take from Spring https://github.com/nicholassmith/restconfigurerdemo

Comment: Thank you for your code. I am able to use it to override one of the RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration methods. However with the newer version of the Spring libraries, there is a change in the class's signature, which I was able to adapt to.